# How is QGIS opening a shapefile with no *.prj file?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

I was wondering how QGIS could open a shapefile with no `*.prj` file (for instance, let's say we have a shapefile with just `*.shp`, `*.dbf` and `*.shx` files). If the *On the fly* reprojection option is activated, the layer is loaded and displayed successfully. I don't understand how such a reprojection is possible if no initial CRS is set.

Comment: I am having a problem where I can open the vector layer, but it is projecting on the fly incorrectly! Even when I manually select the desired CRS the projection is way off. Help

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE, Stacey. Please refrain from posting questions as answers, since nobody will see and thus answer them. Rather open your own question with reference to this one, stating what you tried so far and how you are stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QGIS has a good (in my opinion) mechanism for deciding what to do with input layers that have no coordinate system specification. You can choose one of three ways for QGIS to behave:

1. Always prompt for the correct CRS
2. Always assume that the current project CRS is correct for the input layer
3. Always use a certain default CRS that you choose

You can set which of these three is used in the Settings window, under CRS.

Comment: Thanks @Micha! This means that the reprojection can be false when the current project / default CRS is not the one of the input layer. I have never had any issue so far with an input layer displaying at the wrong place (not the expected one).

Comment: exactly, choices 2 and 3 could lead to false geolocation of your layer

Comment: That is why I strongly suggest choice 1.

Comment: And I think that in a new installation, the default setting is 1, so you should **always** be prompted for the CRS when a layer is loaded without a *.prj

Answer (score 0):

The actual geometry of your shapefile is stored in the SHP file.  The PRJ file is just a text file that tells the GIS what coordinate reference system (CRS) the geometry values are referencing. Because your QGIS project is using the same CRS as the shapefile your data draws in the correct place.  Change the CRS in the project properties with On-The-Fly checked and you will discover that the data no longer display in the correct location.
Here is some more information about shapefiles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile.