# Importing raster to QGIS gives CRS undefined error

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, saga

I make a raster file from LiDAR .las files in SAGA. The CRS of .las is Slovenian National Grid. Then, I export it as GeoTiff (Import/Export - GDAL/OGR - Export GeoTiff). When I import it into QGIS (Project CRS is Slovenian National Grid) I get error CRS was undefined - and it sets it up to Project CRS. Almost everything is fine - Raster correlates with satellite image. It is just that I get little skewed raster. For example, when I try to do map through `qgis2web` I get this black bands at top and bottom:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing .csv to QGIS gives CRS undefined (but not always)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189031/importing-csv-to-qgis-gives-crs-undefined-but-not-always)

Comment: Also, closely related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141364/how-is-qgis-opening-a-shapefile-with-no-prj-file/141366#141366

Answer (score 1):

I think I cracked it. I get skewed raster if my Project CRS is set up as Slovenian National Grid.

If I set it up as WGS84 and import Tif Raster it gives me error and sets up raster CRS to WGS84. That puts tif in the middle of Atlantic. But if I then, correct project CRS back to Slovenian National Grid and also Raster CRS - raster is not skewed and in right position.

Comment: `Settings -> Options -> CRS -> CRS for new layers` should be set to `Prompt for CRS`. Then you can assign the projection if it can not be read from the source file. `Raster -> Projection -> Assign Projection` does basically the same. For the black stripe: Use the identify tool to get the pixel value, and set that as additional nodata value.

Comment: I think i figured out. As i open open Layers plugin and add Google satellite it changes my Project CRS to WGS 84 Mercator. If i put it back to SNG, everything is ok. But black stripe still persist in qgis2web plugin.